# Access objects instantiated in Flex app's MXML file in other AS classes

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I've got an object declared and instantiated in my Flex application's singular MXML file:

```
public var CDN:CDNClass = new CDNClass;
```

I would like to access this same CDN object (and its public methods and properties) in another class declared in a separate .as file as such:

```
package my.vp
{
    import my.media.CDNClass;

    public class SyncConnectorManager
    {

        private function syncMessageReceived(p_evt:SyncSwfEvent):void
        {
            switch (p_evt.data.msgNm)
            {
                case "startStream" :
                    // Play a stream
                    CDN.parsePlayList(p_evt.data.msgVal);
                    break;
```

But when I try to access the public method parsePlayList in the CDN object in a method in the class defined in the .as file, I get the following error:

> Access of undefined property CDN

The reason I want to do this is to break up the logic of my application into multiple AS files and have minimal MXML files, probably only one.

Thanks - any help is much appreciated.  Perhaps my OOD/OOP thinking is not correct here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your OOP thinking is not correct here. You should take in mind differences between classes and instances. This line declares a filed in a current class and initiates it with an instance:

```
public var CDN:CDNClass = new CDNClass;
```

So current instance of your MXML **class** (you can think about it as usual AS class with some other notation) has public field. To operate with `CDN` instance you need something from the following:

- Read the value of `CDN` (as far as it is public) from the instance of your MXML **class**. You need some reference to it for that.
- The instance of your MXML **class** can have a reference to the instance of `SyncConnectorManager` and `SyncConnectorManager` should have a way to inject the value of `CDN` there. Something like:

Your class:

```
package my.vp
{
    import my.media.CDNClass;

    public class SyncConnectorManager
    {
        private var CDN:CDNClass;

        public function SyncConnectorManager(CDN:CDNClass)
        {
             this.CDN = CDN;
        }

        private function syncMessageReceived(p_evt:SyncSwfEvent):void
        {
            switch (p_evt.data.msgNm)
            {
                case "startStream" :
                    // Play a stream
                    CDN.parsePlayList(p_evt.data.msgVal);
                    break;
```

In your case `SyncConnectorManager` class hasn't `CDN` declared (the problem of the compiler error you mentioned) and instantiated (the problem of NPE even if you just declare field).

As the bottom line I can suggest you to follow [ActionScript naming and coding conventions](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Coding+Conventions) to talk other people and team members about your code :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question.  Your response was very helpful.

Comment: What if a class needs to ingest (and access) an object instantiated during run time that can't be passed to it in the class' constructor?  What's the best practice design then, to have a public function of the class assign the run time instantiated class to a private class variable?

Comment: You have at least 3 options: public field (`public var myProp:MyClass`), setter (`public function set myProp(value:MyClass):void`) and public method (`public function setMyProp(value:MyClass):void`). The latter two ways used if you need to perform additional actions on inject. Setter option allows you to use MXML attribute for injecting value.

Comment: Thank you - makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

IT depends on your class architecture.  For your code to work, the `CDNClass` instance must be defined and implemented inside your `SyncConnectorManager`.

Generally, you can always call down into components, but should never call up

One option is to pass the instance of`CDNClass` to a variable inside `SyncConnectorManager`.  Add this variable to your SyncConnectionManager class:

```
public var CDN:CDNClass = new CDNClass;
```

And at some point do this:

```
syncConnectorManagerInstance.CDN = CDN;
```

That way both classes will have access to the same CDN instance and can call methods on it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Your solution makes sense to me.  Is this the typical way public methods/properties of one object are accessed by those external objects that desire to use them?  I'm trying to apply best OOD/OOP practices.  Thanks again.

Comment: @CamdenX Both "Typical approaches" and "Best Practices" are open to interpretation.  Any given best practice comes with many conditions on when that is a good idea and when it isn't.  You could define static methods on your CDNClass and use it across multiple classes. You could also create a Singleton and use it across multiple classes w/o parameter passing.  Some folks use a framework w/ dependency injection to pass lass instances around.  It's hard to say, based on the little we know, which would be best for you.